# Running jQuery code in MEAN.JS stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs

I'm starting to work with NodeJS, and more expecifically with MEAN.JS. I'm trying to run some custom JS code, using JQuery, but no matter where i put the code, it nevers runs as expected. This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tooltips = $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');
    tooltips.tooltip();
});
```

I tried putting it in the body of the page, in a separate script, but nothing. When I debug in Chrome, the variable `tooltips` does not contain any elements, but if I execute the same code in Chrome's console, then it works. It seems to me that despite the `$(document).ready()` thing, the DOM is not ready when the code executes. Maybe AngularJS is doing its magic at the same time and that interferes.

Is there somethign i need to do so that the code will get executed? Do I have to load it after/before something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you using the bootstrap tooltip? if so, there's an angular directive for that. Look at angular-ui

Comment: Otherwise, you should probably do this work inside of a directive.

Comment: Hi @Kevin B. I came by the angular-ui-bootstrap module while researching for this issue. I'm trying it, since it seems a better solution than trying to mix jQuery with AngularJS, and it will all stay in the family ;-) Thanks for your comment.

Comment: There is a clean way to implement this with jquery though, in an angular way. working on a small demo

Comment: Please, put a link to your demo, so that people can find it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a directive instead of applying it in a dom ready:

```
angular.module("myModule")
    .directive('tooltip', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem) {
                $(elem).tooltip();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now, any time you use the `tooltip` or `data-tooltip` attribute on an element in one of your templates, the tooltip plugin will be applied to it.

<sub>Disclaimer: i have not tested this code, and in the end would suggest not using jquery for this. Instead, use angular-bootstrap-tooltip or a similar angular solution</sub>

Comment: I'm selecting this as the correct answer because it addresses the original question and it works like charm. Nevertheless, I encourgae those reading here to use the angular-ui-bootstrap approach mentioned by @Kevin. It works very well, it is Angular (no external JS dependencies needed) and requires less work. You can check angular-ui-bootstrap here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: The answer gives a alternative but not answer the question. What if you have a code which you want to run on Jquery and then eventually convert into angular.In that case how to run Jquery in angular.Here project deadline is also important.

Comment: I don't think any of that would change my answer. If you write code that interacts with the dom in angular, it should be in a directive.

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips will not contains any elements as it is limited to the scope of the anonymous function you specified for `$(document).ready()`. Second, "tooltips" is misspelled in the variable declaration. Try this code to help you debug:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.$tooltips = $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');
    $tooltips.tooltip();
});
```

Now you can go into the console and evaluate the variable `$tooltips` to see if it is there. Note: I prefixed the variable with a `$` to help identify it as a jQuery object. Don't confuse it with the built-in Angular services.

Also, Angular will not execute JavaScript within templates it generates pages from. Be sure to specify external JavaScript in the main page output or place this code to be executed when Angular loads the view.

Comment: Hi @SamT. The misspelling was introduced when writing the question. It is fixed now. I tried your solution without success. I'm also trying another solution that might be even better than using jQuery. Thanks for your time!